# unable to connect Sql Developer using JDBC URL

Tags: jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have jdbc URL as follows.

jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=8888))(LOAD_BALANCE = on)(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER=DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.com)))

When I connect using this URL from sql developer getting error as follows.

> ```
> error ora 00604 error occurred at recursive sql level 1 ora-01882 timezone not found
> ```

I'm using Mac. If I go to `.sqldeveloper` -> 4.1.x -> `product.conf`.

There was a suggestion to change the tz to `AddVMOption -Duser.timezone=CET` . But I dont find any file called  "`sqldeveloper.conf`".

Any idea here.

Comment: I have resolved it. Adding timezone vales in product.conf value resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Resolved it by adding `timezone` values in sqldeveloper in `product.conf` file.

The path was : `/Users/username/.sqldeveloper/4.1.5/product.conf` (in MACS).

Added line was:

```
AddVMOption -Duser.timezone=GMT
```